# How to pass method arguments use as Hash path?

Tags: ruby

E.G.

```
def do_the_thing(file_to_load, hash_path)
  file = File.read(file)
  data = JSON.parse(file, { symbolize_names: true })
  data[sections.to_sym]
end

do_the_thing(file_I_want, '[:foo][:bar][0]')
```

Tried a few methods but failed so far.

Thanks for any help in advance :)

Comment: I can't see from your example why you are looking to pass the `hash_path` and what use it will be once passed.

Comment: Trying to return the specified value from within the definition.

Comment: so `do_the_thing(file_I_want)[:foo][:bar][0]` wouldn't work?

Comment: Ah good point, that does work.  I was overthinking things trying to pass a parameter through.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you missed the parameters names...

Lets assume our file is:

```json
// test.json
{
  "foo": {
    "bar": ["foobar"]
  }
}
```

### Recomended solution

Does your param really need to be a string??
If your code can be more flexible, and pass arguments as they are on ruby, you can use the [Hash dig](https://apidock.com/ruby/v2_5_5/Hash/dig) method:

```ruby
require 'json'

def do_the_thing(file, *hash_path)
  file = File.read(file)
  data = JSON.parse(file, symbolize_names: true)
  data.dig(*hash_path)
end

do_the_thing('test.json', :foo, :bar, 0)
```

You should get

```ruby
"foobar"
```

It should work fine !!

---

*Read the rest of the answer if that doesn't satisfy your question*

---

### Alternative solution (using the same argument)

If you REALLY need to use that argument as string, you can;

Treat your params to adapt to the first solution, it won't be a small or fancy code, but it will work:

```ruby
require 'json'

BRACKET_REGEX = /(\[[^\[]*\])/.freeze

# Treats the literal string to it's correspondent value
def treat_type(param)
  # Remove the remaining brackets from the string
  # You could do this step directly on the regex if you want to
  param = param[1..-2]
  case param[0]
  # Checks if it is a string
  when '\''
    param[1..-2]
  # Checks if it is a symbol
  when ':'
    param[1..-1].to_sym
  else
    begin
      Integer(param)
    rescue ArgumentError
      param
    end
  end
end

# Converts your param to the accepted pattern of 'dig' method
def string_to_args(param)
  # Scan method will break the match results of the regex into an array
  param.scan(BRACKET_REGEX).flatten.map { |match| treat_type(match) }
end

def do_the_thing(file, hash_path)
  hash_path = string_to_args(hash_path)
  file = File.read(file)
  data = JSON.parse(file, symbolize_names: true)
  data.dig(*hash_path)
end
```

so:

```ruby
do_the_thing('test.json', '[:foo][:bar][0]')
```

returns

```ruby
"foobar"
```

This solution though is open to bugs when the "hash_path" is not on an acceptable pattern, and treating it's bugs might make the code even longer

---

### Shortest solution (Not safe)

You can use [Kernel eval](https://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/eval) method which I EXTREMELY discourage to use for security reasons, read the documentation and understand its danger before using it

```ruby
require 'json'

def do_the_thing(file, hash_path)
  file = File.read(file)
  data = JSON.parse(file, symbolize_names: true)
  eval("data#{hash_path}")
end

do_the_thing('test.json', '[:foo][:bar][0]')
```

Comment: Thank you for your in-depth explanation bud, appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

If the procedure you were trying to work with was just extracting the JSON data to an object, you might find yourself using either of the following scenarios:

```
def do_the_thing(file_to_load)
  file = File.read(file)
  data = JSON.parse(file, { symbolize_names: true })
  data[sections.to_sym]
end

do_the_thing(file_I_want)[:foo][:bar][0]
```

or use the `dig` function of [Hash](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-dig) :

```
def do_the_thing(file_to_load, sections)
  file = File.read(file)
  data = JSON.parse(file, { symbolize_names: true })
  data.dig(*sections)
end

do_the_thing(file_I_want, [:foo, :bar, 0])
```